# How to install ffmpeg, ffmpeg-PHP, Mplayer, Mencoder, LAME MP3 encoder for Winxp. php version 5.3.0

Tags: mp3, ffmpeg, mencoder, lame, mplayer

I am newbie in php.Can any body tell me how i install ffmpeg, ffmpeg-PHP, Mplayer, Mencoder in Windows XP and php version should be 5.3.0 or Wamp server release July 11 2009/Xamp Server release 2009/12/23.

I make search on google and i find tutorial but that tutorial work with previous version of php 5.2.8 .

So if some one tell me step by step guide how to install FFMPEG ffmpeg-PHP, Mplayer, Mencoder in winxp.

I am very thankful.

Highly Appreciated
Best Regards
Hasnat

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ehow.com/how_4716678_install-ffmpeg-windows.html

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kc3ylxl1dNA

http://www.bala-krishna.com/compile-and-build-ffmpeg-on-windows-platform-using-mingw-msys/

http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3820177.htm